# Stress Energy Tensor in language of differential forms

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics

The motivation for this is that quantities like the electric current $J$ in maxwell's equations of motion [can be expressed as a differential 3-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_the_electromagnetic_field#Current_3-form,_dual_current_1-form), so that the continuity equation can be written just as
$$dJ=0$$

Which is really nice because it can all be done without defining a metric tensor!

Now the stress-energy tensor has a similar continuity equation but is generally represented as a symmetric 2-tensor. so it can obviously not be represented as a 3 form, but can it somehow be represented potentially in the language of differential forms so that a metric tensor does not have to be defined?

Comment: Exterior derivatives come for free: you don't need any extra structure to define them. Covariant derivatives, on the other hand, need a connection, which may or may not be metric compatible. If it is not, you don't even *need* a metric to define it. But if you do have a metric, then the metric-compatible connection is in fact unique, so it is in this sense special.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Minor correction: The torsion-free metric-compatible connection is unique (Levi-Civita). I think you can have multiple torsive metric-compatible connections. But they are clearly less natural so your point stands.

Comment: @tparker who cares for torsion anyway? :-P

Comment: Regarding the need for a metric: I guess you might argue that the current vector is the basic object, and then you current three-form involves a Hodge star (i.e. the metric). Then again, you could consider the three-form to be the basic object and apply the Hodge dual the other way round...

Comment: @tparker: Thanks for the correction. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you invite "vector bundle-valued differential forms" then you can define $$ T^\mu=T^\mu_{\ \nu}dx^\nu $$ as a "vector field-valued 1-form", then you have $$ d^\nabla\star T^\mu\sim\nabla_\nu T^{\mu\nu}. $$

However the metric is needed both for the definition of $T$ and to take the *covariant exterior derivative* $d^\nabla$ and to take the Hodge dual.

Note that the current $j$ in your example is naturally a vector field, as the current can be obtained by $$ j^\mu=\frac{\delta S_m}{\delta A_\mu}, $$ where $S_m$ is some "matter" Lagrangian that contains $A$ (it is the field-particle interaction Lagrangian basically). So to obtain the 1-form $j$, you need to lower it (*needs the metric*), and then to obtain the  current 3-form $J$, you need to take the Hodge dual $J=\star j$ (*needs the metric*).

Hence while the conservation equation $$ dJ=0 $$ seems metric-independent, it really isn't.

Comment: Isn't the first half of your answer kind of trivial, because you can think of any type-$(p,q+1)$ tensor at all with at least one covariant index as a "type-$(p,q)$-valued one-form" by "picking off" one covariant index?

Comment: Also, I disagree with the second half of your answer; I think that the three-form $J$ is more "natural" for expressing the current density than the vector $j$. The current density is naturally defined as the flux of electric charge through a spatial surface over time, i.e. you integrate it over a timelike hypersurface to get a total charge. This is natural for a three-form, not a vector. Moreover, the coupling term $A_\mu j^\mu$ in the Lagrangian can be expressed in terms of $J$ as $\star(A \wedge J)$. So the continuity equation really is metric-independent.

Comment: On second thought, you don't even need the Hodge star, because within the framework of differential forms the Lagrangian density is naturally thought of as a $D$-form rather than a scalar.

Comment: @tparker To answer the first of your inquiries, while you *can* do this with any tensor field you'd like, and *here* it is kind of cheating, there are many cases when it is very *natural* to think of some tensor fields as differential forms with values in a vector bundle. For example, viewing the curvature tensor as $\Omega^\mu_{\ \nu}=\frac{1}{2}R^\mu_{\ \nu\rho\sigma}dx^\rho\wedge dx^\sigma$ is fairly natural, and considerable simplifications can be gained this way. (contd.)

Comment: @tparker To address the second of your inquiries, I guess that depends on your point of view. From a formal/field theoretic point of view, a current is a response to some kind of symmetry. In the case of EM, the charge current is the response to gauge transformations, whilst the SEM tensor is a kind of "diffeomorphism current". The space here is too little for a detailed discussion, however the point is that if you have a Lagrangian that is completely independent of any metrics, and it has a symmetry, the resulting current is metric-independent and so is its conservation law, but (contd.)

Comment: @tparker ...metric-dependent Lagrangians will have metric-dependent currents, whose conservation laws you *can* formulate in a seemingly metric-independent way, but the metric *will* pop up somewhere if you go deep enough.

Comment: What do you mean that "the metric will pop up if you go deep enough"? The conservation law $dJ = 0$ can be formulated on a smooth manifold with no metric whatsoever. I understand it may be difficult to answer in a comment but I don't understand you claim well enough to make it a separate question.

Comment: @tparker Okay, then let's try this. From an "elementary" point of view, the charge current 3-vector is $\mathbf{j}=\rho\mathbf{v}$, it is related to the velocity field of the charged continuum - so to turn it into a 3-form, you need a metric. From the point of view of field theory, the current appears as the functional derivative of an interaction Lagrangian. In any sufficiently "fundamental" treatment, the interaction Lagrangian cannot be defined without a metric (it will arise from a charged K-G field or a Dirac field, not a $A\wedge J$) term.

Comment: Fair point. You can formulate a Chern-Simons-type theory on a smooth manifold that really doesn't require a metric at all, but I guess coupling it to any kind of matter field with an effective current density requires introducing a metric.

Comment: @tparker Funny i recently went 180° on this (or 360° if you are an electron I guess), and now I also consider 3-form currents to be more natural.

Answer (score 6):

Good question. I suspect that the answer is no, because the (Hilbert) stress-energy tensor is defined to be
$$T_{\mu \nu} := -2 \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} + g_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L},$$
which suggests to me that it may depend fundamentally on the metric structure of spacetime.

Comment: Are you sure your second term should be there? The standard definition of $T_{\mu\nu}$ is just the derivative of the (matter) Lagrangian with respect to the metric, without the diagonal term. Maybe it is a matter of conventions, and you are using one that I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform You can combine the two terms into a single derivative by putting a $\sqrt{g}$ inside the derivative: $-2/\sqrt{g}\ \partial(\sqrt{g} \mathcal{L}) / \partial g^{\mu\nu}$. Doing the product rule eliminates the $\sqrt{g}$'s but leads to the two terms in my answer.

Comment: Oh, I see. It basically boils down to the redefinition $\mathscr L=\sqrt{g}\mathcal L$.

Comment: Yes, exactly...

Answer (score 3):

With the help of a Killing vector field $\xi$ one can define the current 3-form

$$J_\xi = \star\ \iota_\xi T$$

of which you can then take the exterior derivative to obtain the conservation law

$$\operatorname d J_\xi = 0.$$

Note that the metric is *hidden* inside both $T$ and $\xi$.

Comment: Could you explain your notation $\iota_\xi$?

Comment: @tparker [Interior product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_product).

Comment: Just a minor point of order, but I've only ever seen the interior product defined on forms, and I've never seen $T$ in form-form (sorry) — rather, I'd say that this $\iota_\xi T$ quantity is more correctly referred to as contraction as physicists usually describe it: the one-form $\xi^a T_{ab}$.

Comment: Also, I'd sooner emphasize that the metric is (barely) hidden inside the Hodge dual.

Comment: ...and *definitely* in the very notion of a Killing field.